# Dynamically adding value to drop down

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Hi below is my code to dynamically populate the drop down. But when i am trying to do so nothing is getting populated in dropdown. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<% List<String> w = new ArrayList<String>();
    w.add("John");
    w.add("Joseph");
    %>
    <td><select id="web" name="web">

         <c:forEach var="item" items="${w}">
              <option><c:out value="${item}"/></option>
         </c:foreach>

    </select></td>
```

Comment: are your imports done properly... for List ?

Answer (score 0):

end your forEach properly

```
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Done but still have issues

Answer (score 0):

It seems like  the variable scope issue. EL works only on scoped variables. So it can't access scriptlet varialbes.  Please try the below

```
<% List w = new ArrayList();
    w.add("John");
    w.add("Joseph");        
    pageContext.setAttribute("w", w);    
    %>
    <td>
    <select id="web" name="web">
         <c:forEach var="item" items="${w}">
              <option><c:out value="${item}"/></option>
         </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted to do is have a dynamic drop down then you can set the values via a `<c:set>` with a comma delimited list, then instead of a `<c:forEach>` use a `<c:forTokens delims="," ...>`

For example:

```
<td>
    <c:set var="w">John,Joseph</c:set>
    <select id="web" name="web">
        <c:forTokens var="item" delims="," items="${w}">
            <option><c:out value="${item}" /></option>
        </c:forTokens>
    </select>
</td>
```